# Need help saving specific json parsed information to a json

Tags: node.js, json, api

Where could I find documentation on the following:

I'm fetching a public API that has a load of information and saving it to a local json file. I then want to take that json file and simplify it with only some information from each array (has multiple), and then store it in a separate json file to call at a later date.

This is the code I have so far...

````
import fs from 'fs';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


export function fetchAndUpdate(){
    const options = {method: 'GET'};
    fetch('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=0xeFdD9A85E4bb37E37Bc834901bD3c631C9539d54&offset=0&limit=300', options)
    .then(function(response){ return response.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ 
        let tempData = null;
        tempData = data;
        let formatted = JSON.stringify(tempData, null, 2);
        fs.writeFileSync('./data/raw-collections.json', formatted, function(error, result) { if(error) console.log('error', error)})

        
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}```
````

Comment: what is the result of the above snippet? what is the output? was the file created?

Comment: Hello @Carve, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please also update with the issue you are facing with the current approach.